# Spring Cloud Gateway not starting when deployed as WAR showing webFluxConversionService error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

I'm trying to do a sample with Spring Cloud Gateway for JWT authentication and URL routing purpose.

All is running well when i run as a JAVA application or using Embedded Tomcat Container but when the same is deployed to a Tomcat server as a War, then i ge the below dependency injection error.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 4 of method routeDefinitionRouteLocator in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=webFluxConversionService)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService' in your configuration.

I have tried adding jars related to spring web flux but the error did not go

my POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web-reactive -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
    <finalName>mxgateway</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <outputDirectory>E:/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps</outputDirectory> 
                </configuration> </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The gateway configuration is

```
package com.gateway.gateway;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.gateway.gateway.bean.ProgramRouteDetail;
import com.gateway.gateway.security.CustomGatewayFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class GatewayApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Autowired
    CustomGatewayFilter customGatewayFilter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }


    public List<ProgramRouteDetail> filterRequest(){
        List<ProgramRouteDetail> programRouteDetails = new ArrayList<ProgramRouteDetail>();
        for(int i =0;i<=2;i++){
            ProgramRouteDetail detail = new ProgramRouteDetail();
            detail.setDestUri("http://localhost:9090");
            detail.setProgramId("users");
            detail.setPath("/user/**");
            programRouteDetails.add(detail);
        }   
        return programRouteDetails;
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
      SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(GatewayApplication.class);
    }
    public RouteLocator constructRouteAndFilters(RouteLocatorBuilder builder ){
        Builder routes = builder.routes();
        List<ProgramRouteDetail> programRouteDetails  = filterRequest();
        for(ProgramRouteDetail programDetail : programRouteDetails){
            routes.route(p -> p.path(programDetail.getPath()).filters(f->f.filter(customGatewayFilter)).uri(programDetail.getDestUri()));
        }
        return routes.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return constructRouteAndFilters(builder);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Spring Cloud Gateway does not support WAR deployments. It is based on Spring Webflux and Spring Boot does not support war deployments of webflux.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file):

> Because Spring WebFlux does not strictly depend on the Servlet API and
>   applications are deployed by default on an embedded Reactor Netty
>   server, War deployment is not supported for WebFlux applications.

Comment: That will not be an issue because SpringBootServletInitializer  will take care of that After adding the annotation with @EnableWebFlux the war has deployed without any issues but now i'm getting 404 error for any request

Comment: I just told you we don't support war deploys. Whatever issue you have, it's not supported.

Comment: So is the gateway meant to be accessed only using jar? Im trying to protect my microservices using the gateway.shoukd

Comment: So is there any alternative ? How should i then protect my microservices using the cloud gateway

Comment: Gateway can only be deployed as an executable jar. Otherwise you could try zuul.

Comment: isn't spring cloud the successor to zuul? i need to configure dynamic routing which seems not possible with zuul. In spring cloud i can configure routing path from using java but with zuul i can do that only using application properties which is hardcoded